# Java Logger does not print anything to console

Tags: java, logging

I'm just starting to learn about Logger in Java; however, I don't understand how it works.

I have this code right after my class declaration:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
```

Then in my methods I use it like this (examples):

```
LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "Testing");
LOGGER.info("More testing...");

...
} catch(Exception e) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e);
}
```

But nothing prints to the console. Is it being saved in a file somewhere or am I just using it incorrectly?

I am using Eclipse Mars 2 with Java 1.6.0_22 if it makes a difference.

**EDIT**: I am using the `java.util.logging.Logger` library.

Comment: Added the library to OP.

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the project explorer in Eclipse to see if any files were generated?

Comment: I did; even closed Eclipse and reopened. There were no new files.

Comment: Did you try to call LOGGER.getHandlers() and check the list of handlers assigned to the logger? Maybe console handler is not assigned?

Comment: Do I print it in `System.out`? If so, I get this: `java.util.logging.Handler`.

Comment: Nope, rather check in debugger what is the class of handler instance. You can also try to add a handler by calling LOGGER.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler()). Try to play with LOGGER.setLevel(Level.ALL), maybe logging is off.

Comment: I tried your code and prints this: 
jun 08, 2016 11:46:32 PM Methods.MyClass main
INFORMACIÓN: More testing...

Comment: @Kamil Thank you! Adding the handler made it work. I see the same thing now Umpa.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's what you should know, `java.util.Logging` is controlled by a root logger file found in the JRE/lib folder called `logging.properties` that defaults to Level.INFO, hence Fine messages are not displayed by default since FINE is lower than INFO,

```
 private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());

 Handler handlerObj = new ConsoleHandler();
 handlerObj.setLevel(Level.ALL);
 LOGGER.addHandler(handlerObj);
 LOGGER.setLevel(Level.ALL);
 LOGGER.setUseParentHandlers(false);
```

Now you can use your LOGGER object just fine and should work. checkout [Java Logging Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html)

```
 LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "finest");
```

Remember that there's a reason the Log Level is set to FINE, so,lowering the level could also print unnecessary info from core libraries. Let me know if it helps.

Regards Douglas

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful! I'll checkout more from the overview.

Answer (score 2):

My assumption is that you are using Log4J. If that is correct, the logger should be saving to a file by default not printing to a console (which is usually done with System.out.println("message")). Do you have a log4j.properties file?

Comment: I am not using Log4J. Added the library to the OP in an edit. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me in a brand new Eclipse project.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Foobar {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Foobar.class.getName());;

    public Foobar() {
        LOGGER.info("Constructed");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foobar();
    }
}
```

[image: eclipse console]

Comment: My class is written the same way as well. Thank you for the help, I had to add the handler for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The nothing is displayed because there are no handlers attached to the Logger with name MyClass.class.getName();

But,there is one handler by default in the **parent logger instance**.This handler is ConsoleHandler that has log level **INFO**.

It's easy to verify:

```
public class StackAnswerAboutLogger {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(StackAnswerAboutLogger.class.getName());
private static final Logger PARENT_LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LOGGER.info("Count of LOGGER handlers: " + Integer.toString(LOGGER.getHandlers().length));
    LOGGER.info("Count of PARENT_LOGGER handlers: " + Integer.toString(LOGGER.getHandlers().length));
    Handler defaultConsoleHandler = PARENT_LOGGER.getHandlers()[0];
    LOGGER.info("Default Console Handler Log Level: " + defaultConsoleHandler.getLevel().toString());
  }

}
```

Output:

```
Jan 10, 2020 10:23:53 PM init.StackAnswerAboutLogger main
INFO: Count of LOGGER handlers: 0
Jan 10, 2020 10:23:54 PM init.StackAnswerAboutLogger main
INFO: Count of PARENT_LOGGER handlers: 0
Jan 10, 2020 10:23:54 PM init.StackAnswerAboutLogger main
INFO: Default Console Handler Log Level: INFO
```

To display the log with ANY level, you could configure either PARENT_LOGGER handlers or LOGGER ones.

```
Handler defaultConsoleHandler = PARENT_LOGGER.getHandlers()[0];
LOGGER.info("Default log level of PARENT_LOGGER: " +PARENT_LOGGER.getLevel().toString());
LOGGER.info("Default Console Handler Log Level: "+defaultConsoleHandler.getLevel().toString());
defaultConsoleHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
PARENT_LOGGER.setLevel(Level.ALL);
LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "here is finest log");
LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "here is severe log");
```

Output:

```
Jan 10, 2020 10:38:10 PM init.StackAnswerAboutLogger main
INFO: Default log level of PARENT_LOGGER: INFO
Jan 10, 2020 10:38:10 PM init.StackAnswerAboutLogger main
INFO: Default Console Handler Log Level: INFO
Jan 10, 2020 10:38:10 PM init.StackAnswerAboutLogger main
FINEST: here is finest log
Jan 10, 2020 10:38:10 PM init.StackAnswerAboutLogger main
SEVERE: here is severe log
```